# Extending horizontal urinal flush handle vertically

Tags: bathroom, toilet, product-recommendation

We have a urinal used by small young children where the handle is too high.  We'd like to extend it lower so that it could be reached by them.

My only thought is kind of ugly and hackish -- a couple of zip ties, a chain, key/split rings, and perhaps some kind of handle.

Another option is carefully drilling out the handle (vertically) and putting a stainless steel eye hook through it, then attaching a chain, etc.  Then at least it won't slide and I can avoid the beautiful zip ties.

I'd really prefer an off-the-shelf solution -- perhaps there is a product that exists that does this to make the handle handicap accessible.  I haven't had any luck searching.

Is there a product (or better suggestion) available?

[image: Urinal Flush Hardware]

Comment: Unless the pipe from the flusher to the urinal itself is exceptionally long, I'm having trouble envisioning a urinal that is low enough for someone to effectively use, but with a handle so high that they can't flush it. But if that is the case, then the "clean" solution is have a plumber lower the handle to a more suitable level in relation to the urinal bowl. Or, replace it with a waterless urinal (and some water agencies/communities will help pay for that)

Comment: @Johnny -- if you're talking about an actual *urinal* (instead of a conventional toilet), a floormount urinal would be low enough for anyone to use, but with the flush handle mounted high enough small kids can't reach it.

Comment: What about putting a small stool next to the urinal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nice thing about children is that they will grow larger and this problem will eliminate itself (although this will then be the least of your worries). So, you only need a temporary fix.

I am envisioning a piece of clear plastic tubing with an internal diameter close to the size of the handle. (A hose clamp could be used, if absolutely needed, to keep it from coming off.)

If the tubing is sized right, then once lubricated with dish soap or something similar, it could be forced on to the end of the handle and once the soap dries it will be attached well enough to stay by itself. The tubing will probably come on a roll and have a slight curve to it anyway that could be used to curve it down for a small child to reach. Otherwise, a 90° fitting could be added to get it into the proper position.

Once the child is tall enough the tubing can be carefully scored with a razor knife until it peels off of the handle. This would then leave the handle undamaged.

Good luck!

Comment: Creative and easy - I like it as an option!

Comment: Most places with urinals and small children will have a recurring/continuous supply of small children. Urinals in a home setting are exceedingly rare, and in institutional settings there's typically a renewable/permanent supply of small persons justifying a permanent solution. I'd prefer a rod connection to a foot-operated lever on the floor if refitting the valve, or a foot valve if replacing it. Those were a nice original feature of some 1920's era buildings I used to frequent...apparently an idea so far ahead of its time that its time hasn't come yet, in the mass market.

Comment: Yes, this is in a daycare / preschool setting.

Answer (score 5):

The best hack is one that has already been specifically engineered:

[image]

They make remote buttons for them, the pictured style is one of several options. Go to a good commercial plumbing shop and you should be able to get more info.